# Blender 2.81a file created in Windows behaves weird in Linux

Tags: windows, linux, compatibility

I have students learning Blender doing the Blender Guru Donut Tutorial. While doing this, a few of them have moved to another room. The difference is that they started on Windows 10 PCs and now try to continue on Linux Mint PCs.

The file opens in Linux Blender 2.81a but the donut is not there and the program crash when going to rendered mode.

Among other things, I tried to work around the problem, appending things from the saved windows blend file to a fresh Blender instance in Linux. There I see that there are more objects in the folder when appending in Linux than trying the same in windows. Apart from the expected "Donut", "Icing" etc there are also additional "Donut original" and "Icing original". If I append the "original" objects they appear in the Linux scene, while the non.original objects are not shown and crash in render.

Anyone have seen and/or have any knowledge about this?

Linkt to downloading a bagel blend file with this behaviour:
https://easyupload.io/stpxww

Comment: Have you confirmed that the Linux Mint install works correctly on its own? Can you load other blend files into that version without issues?

Comment: Non-original files have higher polygon count so it may be a performance or graphics driver issues

Comment: Thank you for the replies! High polygon count seems to be causing the problem. In the tutorial, subsurface modifiers are applied to create a mesh for more detailed sculpting and those high polygon files can not open or crash, also in other blend files.

One interesting thing is that I can open a lower res bagel in Linux Blender and increase the number of polygons, applying subsurface modifiers and sculpt away, with no apparent performance toll. Then, when I save the file and try to reopnen it, Blender crashes. It does open in Win10. Not that the win10 and Linux computers are identical.

Comment: Last line should read "Note that the win10 and Linux computers are identical"